# Detecting if Keyboard is connected to Windows Surface?

Tags: javascript, c++, windows-8, tablet

I am trying to detect when the keyboard is attached or detached from surface. Currently what i am doing is seting a function through SetInterval for every 1 sec and then calling the API for mouse detection ( apparently keyboard is always returning true ).

```
var mouse = new Windows.Devices.Input.MouseCapabilities().
```

Based on the return value i am doing my work. Everything is working fine but its slow.

Can i do something else ? Like instead of pulling , is their something pushing equivalent to this.

Moving things from Js to Cpp will improve this ? If yes , how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just from browsing the API docs, I think the [DeviceWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.aspx) events might be what you're looking for.